# Need key index to 0 based on subcat element value in array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
    (
        [product_id] => 79
        [sub_category] => 63
    )
    Array
    (
        [product_id] => 89
        [sub_category] => 63
    )
    Array
    (
        [product_id] => 9
        [sub_category] => 6
    )
    Array
    (
        [product_id] => 90
        [sub_category] => 6
    )
```

I have an array named $row and I am getting these results.I am using codeignitor.Please help me to resolve it out.I need array key baed on subcategory values.I have mentioned below both array what I am getting and what I need .Please help me to resolve it asap.I need it should give key as based on subcategory.I mainy need subcategory id and then all its products id.All result I get in one array named row

```
Array
(
   [0]=> [product_id] => 79
    [sub_category] => 63
[1]=>
    [product_id] => 89
    [sub_category] => 63
)
Array
(
  [0]=>  [product_id] => 9
    [sub_category] => 6
[1]=>
    [product_id] => 90
    [sub_category] => 6
)
```

Comment: Hi Priyanka, do you need products to be group by sub category id?

Comment: @aljx0409 Yes.Thank You in advance! I have used $this->db->order_by('sub_category', 'desc'); in query

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$final = [];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (!isset($final[$row['sub_category']])) {
        $final[$row['sub_category']] = [];
    }

    $final[$row['sub_category']][] = $row;
}
```

`$final` array will contain the data that you need.

Let me know if this is what you wanted?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 79
        )[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 63
        )Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 89
        )[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 63
        ) but it givesresult like that

Comment: Hi @priyankaarora, so do you want 1 array with all the data or you want 2 different array as a result?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 79
            [sub_category] => 63
           
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 80
            [sub_category] => 63
            
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 81
            [sub_category] => 63
           
        )
  )
  
I need result lik this

<div id="subid">63</div>
<div>productid:79</div>
<div>Productid:80</div>
<div>Productid:81</div>

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for group by the array by `sub_category`, you can do this by using `array_walk` and `array_values`, in simple you can use `foreach` OR `for`

```
$r = [];
array_walk($a, function($v, $k) use (&$r){
  $r[$v['sub_category']][] = $v;
});
print_r(array_values($r));
```

Live example : https://3v4l.org/dj4Xa

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 79
        )[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 63
        )Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 89
        )[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 63
        ) but it givesresult like that